# combine two sets of floats on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have a folio page. When a user clicks link 'design' - all the relevant design images are shown. When the user clicks 'art' all the relevant art images are shown

What I would like to have is an 'all' button which combines them all.

The two sets are contained in divs which turn on and off perfectly in the below javascript. What I need is to add to the script so there is a function that says - click all and display both, instead of one or the other.

When have them both turned on, they flow into each other fine so thats not an issue. I'll keep the code as brief as I can. I have only icluded one image in each section but there is actually 6-7.

Thanks in advance!

my html is:

```
<div class="sectiondivider">
             <div id="ThumbLinks">   
                        <a href="#" name="thumbs" id="all">ALL</a>  
                        <a href="#" name="thumbs" id="art">ART</a><br />   
                        <a href="#" name="thumbs" id="gd">GD</a>   
            </div> 
</div>

<div class="thumb_container">
            <div class="thumbs" id="gd_info">
                     <div class="flex_one">
                         <img class="icon-image" src="gd.jpg"/>
                      </div>    
           </div>
           <div class="thumbs" id="art_info">
                     <div class="flex_one">
                         <img class="icon-image" src="art.jpg"/>
                      </div>    
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.gd_thumbs {
    display:none;
}


.art_thumbs {
    display:none;
}

.icon-image {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    opacity:1;
}

.flex_one {
    width:28%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#000;
    border: solid 2px rgb(0,81,88);
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left:4%;
    margin-top:4%;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#ThumbLinks a').click(function(e) {
     // do something fancy
     return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
     e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
});

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("div.thumbs:gt(0)").hide();  // to hide all div except for the first one
     $('#ThumbLinks a').click(function(selected) {
        var getID = $(this).attr("id");      
        var projectImages = $(this).attr("name");      

        $("div.thumbs").hide();       
        $("#" + getID + "_info" ).fadeIn( "slow" ); 


    });  
});
```

Comment: Why can't you just have a button event that calls `.show()` on both `#gd_info` and `#art_info`?

Comment: I'm sure you could but unfortunately I have no knowledge of Javascript. I tried to decipher the existing to see if I could write a button event myself but I have only just finished learning HTML and CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet.

It just checks if the link's id is `all` to show them all and, if not, keeps on with your old code. I tried to keep it as short as possible.

**EDIT**: I think the effect is nicer if, first of all, you hide them all

```
  $('#ThumbLinks a').click(function(e) {
    // first we hide them all (for a nicer effect)
    $("div.thumbs").hide();
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "all")
    // if the ThumbLink's id is 'all' we fade in all the divs 
      $(".thumbs").fadeIn("slow");
    else
    // if not, we fade in just the correct one 
      $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_info").fadeIn("slow");
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.thumbs:gt(0)").hide(); // hide all div except for the first one

  $('#ThumbLinks a').click(function(e) {
    // fisrt we hide them all (for a nicer effect)
    $("div.thumbs").hide();
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "all")
    // if the ThumbLink's id is 'all' fade in all the divs 
      $(".thumbs").fadeIn("slow");
    else
    // if not, we fade in just the correct one 
      $("#" + $(this).attr("id") + "_info").fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.thumbs {
  color: white;
}
.gd_thumbs {
  display: none;
}
.art_thumbs {
  display: none;
}
.icon-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex_one {
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #000;
  border: solid 2px rgb(0, 81, 88);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-top: 4%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sectiondivider">
  <div id="ThumbLinks">
    <a href="#" name="thumbs" id="all">ALL</a> 
    <a href="#" name="thumbs" id="art">ART</a>
    <br />
    <a href="#" name="thumbs" id="gd">GD</a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="thumb_container">
  <div class="thumbs" id="gd_info">
    <div class="flex_one">
      I'm the GD div
      <img class="icon-image" src="gd.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbs" id="art_info">
    <div class="flex_one">
      I'm the ART div
      <img class="icon-image" src="art.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. You are amazing, thank you very much. Us newbies would be lost without help here :)

Comment: @ShereeWalker: Glad it helped!